# CountIf and Subtotal

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a series of data columnar that I am wanting to use a countif for visible cells only that have the value 1.  I can do either formula with no problem, CountIF, or SubTotal for visible cells, however when I try to combin them I get lost. Here is an example of my formula segments.
    =CountIf(I5:I6500,1)
    =SubTotal(3,I5:I6000)

How do I combine the two formulas to have a single formula that counts all instances of the number 1 in a column while not counting hidden cells due to filtering???

Comment: The column with the 1's & 0's is not the primary column I will be filtering by.  There are other columns with Region, Office nbr, etc. that will be the primary filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desert Spider,
This worked for me:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(I5:I6000=(C12)),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(I5,ROW(I5:I6000)-ROW(I5),0)))

OR  (the above uses another cell value to determine your query, the below uses your user input (X))

=SUMPRODUCT(--(I5:I6000="X"),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(I5,ROW(I5:I6000)-ROW(I5),0)))
```

**Credit to:**
pgc01
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/600223-subtotal-countif.html#post2971937

Answer (score 0):

Filter on `ColumnI` (as well) to select `1` and the count should appear at the bottom left of your screen (just to the right of `Ready`, so no formula may be needed.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am aware of the auto summary information in excel and that is not providing what I am looking for. The auto summary does not grant the conditional counting that I am looking for.